Data annotations is not working as expected even after applying required attribute
I have a model class in .NET 6.0 and applied data annotations. I have extension class ApiRequestValidation that returns validationresults after checking the JSON in the request body.
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class ExternalNotificationRequest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Appointment details
    /// </summary>
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please provide a appointment object values.")]
    [JsonProperty("appointment")]
    public Appointment? Appointment { get; set; }
}

public class Appointment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Notification type such as Create/Update/Delete
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please provide a appointment type. Valid values are  CREATE,UPDATE,DELETE.")]
    public string? Type { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// appointment public id
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("publicId")]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    [MinLength(64)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Please provide an appointment public id.")]
    public string? PublicId { get; set; }
}

 public static class ApiRequestValidation
 {
    public static bool IsValid(this object request, out ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults)
    {
        validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
        return Validator.TryValidateObject(request, new ValidationContext(request), validationResults, true);
    }
 }

I'm utilizing ApiRequestValidation in an Azure function:
ExternalNotificationRequest externalNotificationRequest = new ExternalNotificationRequest();
_logger.LogInformation("{FunctionName} Request Body: {requestBody}", functionName, requestBody);

externalNotificationRequest = 
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExternalNotificationRequest>(requestBody) 
        ?? new ExternalNotificationRequest();

// Validate Data Annotations.
if (!externalNotificationRequest.IsValid(validationResults: out var validationResults))
{
    return messageExtensions.RenderApiMessage(_logger, StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, validationResults.Select(s => s.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault(), functionName, validationResults.Select(s => s.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault().ToString());
}

Sample JSON data:
{
    "appointment": {
        "type": "create",
        "publicId": ""
    }
}

Test case: with this JSON, my data annotation is not working properly. I am not getting error message whenever publicId is empty or null.
What am I missing?

Are you using azure function http trigger or which trigger are you using?

Yes HTTP Trigger.

provided the answer, check it @PavanKumar GVVS

It is working fine for me using below code:
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp159
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> rithlogger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            rithlogger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
            rithlogger.LogInformation("Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! Function Started ");
            string rithrb = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            rithlogger.LogInformation("Request Body: {requestBody}", rithrb);
            ExternalNotificationRequest ENR;
            try
            {
                ENR = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExternalNotificationRequest>(rithrb);
            }
            catch (JsonException ex)
            {
                rithlogger.LogError(ex, "Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! Error deserializing request body.");
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! Invalid JSON format.");
            }

            if (ENR.Appointment == null)
            {
                rithlogger.LogError("Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! Appointment object is missing.");
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! Appointment object is missing. Please provide an appointment.");
            }

            ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults;
            if (!ENR.IsValid(out validationResults))
            {
                var errMsg = validationResults.Select(vr => vr.ErrorMessage).FirstOrDefault();
                var memnam = validationResults.Select(vr => vr.MemberNames.FirstOrDefault()).FirstOrDefault()?.ToString();
                rithlogger.LogError("Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! Validation failed for {MemberName}: {ErrorMessage}", memnam, errMsg);
                return new BadRequestObjectResult($"Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! Validation failed for {memnam}: {errMsg}");
            }

            return new OkObjectResult("Hello Rithwik Bojja!!! Request processed successfully!");
        }
    }

    public class ExternalNotificationRequest
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide an appointment.")]
        [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Please provide an appointment public id.")]
        public RithAppoint? Appointment { get; set; }

        public bool IsValid(out ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults)
        {
            validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
            if (Appointment != null)
            {
                return Validator.TryValidateObject(Appointment, new ValidationContext(Appointment), validationResults, true);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public class RithAppoint
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide an appointment type.")]
        [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Please provide an appointment public id.")]
        public string? Type { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide an appointment public id.")]
        [MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Please provide an appointment public id.")]
        public string? PublicId { get; set; }
    }
}

Output:
If given empty {} it gives:

If we give input with type being empty :
{
    "appointment": {
        "type": "",
        "publicId":"8"
    }
}


If we give input with publicId being empty :
{
    "appointment": {
        "type": "create",
        "publicId":""
    }
}


If we give all values correctly:


Not worked for me. I created a brand new Azure HTTP trigger Function with .NET 6 and tested.
